# Can't Run WCF methods from a browser

Tags: c#, wcf

I created a simple WCF service application, and try to change the WCF code, that it will also be able to be called from a client browser, but it only successfully runs from a WCF client.

running from browser, doesn't call the WCF service (but no error message in browser).

code:

Contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet] 
    string Test();

    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet] 
    string GetData(int value);
}
```

Implementation:

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public string GetData(int value)
    {
        return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
    }

    public string Test()
    {
        return "test success";
    }
}
```

Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Project URL:

```
http://localhost:1507/
```

browser URL line - test method:

```
http://localhost:1507/Service1.svc/Test
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean "run from the browser"? Run what? `Test` is an operation, not a URL. You can't call it with GET.  That's not a limitation of WCF, that's exactly how a (SOAP) Web Service works. Did you confuse Web Services with REST APIs perhaps?

Comment: because the WCF service runs from the localhost, I ran from the local browser the line "http://localhost:1507/Service1.svc/Test".

Comment: I changed the binding to binding="webHttpBinding", that it will run with REST API.

Comment: If you want a REST API, use Web API, not WCF. WCF REST API was added as a stop-gap until the release of ASP.NET MVC and Web API. Even the JSON serializer is deprecated (JavascriptSerializer). ASP.NET Web API uses Json.NET

Comment: I only now WCF, and i have a interview tomorrow, where i will need to create a server side. There is way to change the WCF, that it will be able to run from browser?

Answer (score 1):

at first you need to develop a restful service. please follow this config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="SoapBinding" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <mexHttpBinding>
        <binding name="MexBinding" />
      </mexHttpBinding>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="RestBinding" />
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <client />

    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="YourServiceName.Service1 ">
        <endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SoapBinding" name="Soap" contract="EyeMan.IService1 " />
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="Web" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="RestBinding" name="Rest" contract="EyeMan.IService1 " />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MexBinding" name="Mex" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Web">
          <webHttp helpEnabled="true" defaultBodyStyle="Bare" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>

      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

now you can create a `EndPoint` with `GET` method:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = @"/GetData?value={value}")]
public string GetData(int value)
{
    return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
}
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = @"/Test")]
public string Test()
{
    return "test success";
}
```

now you are good to go. just call `http://localhost:1507/Service1.svc/Test` on your browser.